# Get last record in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, lastinsertid

Using this php code:

```
try{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
    // INSERT CLEAN DATA INTO TABLE…
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("
    INSERT INTO Fan(fanNm,fanEmail,fanPass,fanDynamSalt)
    VALUES('$userName','$userEmailAddress','$userPassword','$dynamSalt')"
    );
    $sth->execute();
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ## Set Session Var for this PK ID in Fan table that is being created ##
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $_SESSION['newUserSessID'] = mysql_insert_id();
    echo "<strong style='color:#fff;'>".$_SESSION['newUserSessID']."</strong>";
} //try

catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Oops, We're experiencing an error.";
        file_put_contents('/PDODBConnectionErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
} //catch
```

It inserts FINE into the database, but I am using `echo "<strong style='color:#fff;'>".$_SESSION['newUserSessID']."</strong>";` to echo out that value and it ALWAYS returns a zero.

Even if I run :

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID( ) 
FROM Fan
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It gives me output like

```
0
0
```

(since there is two rows in database table)

Anyone?

Comment: mysql_insert_id() retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query. Are any of your columns AUTO_INCREMENTS? What are the other fields in Fan?

Comment: HTML tags require double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`) which you have in your `echo` statement.

Comment: @AmitBhargava - yes the PK is auto increment.

Comment: @Jon - I dont believe that's the issue.

Comment: @user975947 I never said it was, that's why it was a comment, not an answer. But HTML does require double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `mysql_insert_id` as that isn't part of PDO (which is what you're using to interact with the database in this instance).

Instead use `PDO::lastInsertId()`:

```
$_SESSION['newUserSessID'] = $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Perfect, Sorry bit new to PDO. That was easy. Thanks @Ezequiel Muns!

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `PDO` with generic `MySQL` functions. The problem is the `mysql_last_insert` has no resource, and so it returns 0 for false. Don't mix `PDO` with generic `MySQL` functions.

To get the last insert id in PDO, do this:
`$dbh->lastInsertId()`

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php